# Doctors in a hospital - Conditional probability problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> In a hospital, patients are treated by doctors $A, B,$ and $C$. Doctor $A$ treats $50\%$ of the patients, doctor $B$ treats $20\%$ and doctor $C$ treats $30\%$. $3\%$ of doctor $A'$s diagnoses are false, $2\%$ of doctor $B'$s diagnoses are false and $5\%$ of doctor $C'$s diagnoses are false.
>
> To improve the diagnosis process, doctor $B$ has recently been double-checking the work of his colleagues $A$ and $C$ and finding $80\%$ of all their false diagnoses and correcting them. The diagnoses of doctor $B$ remain unchecked. What is the probability of being misdiagnosed at this hospital?

Here are my thoughts:

Let $A$ be the event of being treated by doctor $A$, $B$ by doctor $B$, $C$ by doctor $C$ and $F$ the event of being misdiagnosed *before doctor $B$ started double-checking the other doctors' work*. It follows:

$P(A) = 0.5$,
$P(B) = 0.2$,
$P(C) = 0.3$.

$P(F) = P(A) \cdot P(F | A) + P(B)\cdot P(F | B) + P(C) \cdot P(F | C) = 0.5 \cdot 0.03 + 0.2 \cdot 0.02 + 0.3 \cdot 0.05 = 0.034.$

Let $F'$ be the event of being misdiagnosed after $B$ started double-checking the other doctors' work. Then:

$P(F') = (P(A) \cdot P(F | A) + P(C) \cdot P(F | C)) \cdot 0.8 + P(B)\cdot P(F | B) = (0.5 \cdot 0.03 + 0.3 \cdot 0.05) \cdot 0.8 + 0.2 \cdot 0.02 = 0.028.$

Which is as expected less than $P(F).$

---

However, my textbook gives $0.01$ as the solution. Where's my mistake?

Comment: Note:  I'm not sure the problem is well posed.  First of all, when $B$ checks $A$'s work, say, there is, presumably a chance that $B$ will err and produce a false diagnosis where, in fact, $A$ was correct.  What happens in that case?  Secondly, are we to assume that $B$ corrects a given false diagnosis with probability $.8$ independent of the source?  That seems likely to have been intended, but it does not follow from what is given.

Comment: @lulu We can assume that $B$ finds $80\%$ of the doctors' mistakes with $100\%$ efficiency. For your second point, $B$ corrects $80\%$ of $A'$s and $B'$s work, but he still makes false diagnoses of his own with a probability of $0.02$ (these diagnoses are independent of those of $A$ and $C$ and are "checked" by no one).

Comment: I don't understand.  The assumption you want is that, if $A$ is correct, then $B$ agrees with $A$ with probability $1$, but if $A$ is in error, then $B$ will correct that error with probability $.8$?  But that seems profoundly unphysical.

Comment: @lulu $B$ will correct $80\%$ of all $A'$s errors (and $80\%$ of all $C'$s errors).

Comment: Yes, but there should be a chance that $B$ introduces a new error.  It seems bizarre to suppose that $B$ is flawless precisely in those cases where $A$ or $C$ happen to have been correct.  In any case, making that assumption, the answer would appear to be $.009$ which does not match the official result.

Comment: To get $.009$:  there are three scenarios, according to whomever your initial doctor was.  in scenario $A$ the probability that you were treated by $A$ and got a false diagnosis that $B$ failed to correct is $.5\times .03\times .2$  For scenario $B$ we get $.2\times .02$ and for $C$ we get $.3\times .05\times .2$  and adding these we get $.009$ barring arithmetic blunder.

Comment: @lulu This is correct. My mistake was multiplying $P(A) \cdot P(F | A) + P(C) \cdot P(F | C)$ by $0.8$ instead of $0.2$. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since we're looking for the probability of being misdiagnosed:

$$P(F') = (P(A) \cdot P(F | A) + P(C) \cdot P(F | C)) \cdot 0.\color{red}{2} + P(B)\cdot P(F | B) = 0.01.$$